# Websites take a long time to connect to

Tags: internet-connection

I have been back and forth with ISP's, technicians from the local telecom company, testing this, testing that and I just cannot figure it out.

There are days that my internet runs so smoothly it makes me smile and there are days it makes me want to commit a crime against the internet itself.

Is there anything I can run to monitor my machine on a regular basis that will flag any kind of irregular behaviour that might be benchmarked against other people's machines?

If I tell you I have tried everything, I would not even know where to begin to list them all.

The frustrating part is when everyone tells me everything is running properly but clearly it is not.

Essentially, if there were some software, I could run just to flag something out of the ordinary, that would really help as it feels as though I searching on the dark at the moment.

Any advice at this stage would be great please?

**EDIT: What I have tried.**

- Changing ISP's
- Having technicians come out and test, with their equipment. (Problem happened for them too)
- Testing on another machine.
- Thought it might be the auto backups happening but changed the time for that and that wasn't the cause either.
- Tried another router.
- Testing at different times of the day

Here is a Tracert I am doing to Google.com from my wife's machine:

```
1     1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.254
2   559 ms   738 ms   891 ms  196-215-156-1.dynamic.isadsl.co.za [196.215.156.1]
3   764 ms   609 ms   909 ms  cdsl1-ctn-vl2376.ip.isnet.net [196.38.72.205]
4   398 ms   545 ms   834 ms  196.35.115.128
5   444 ms   271 ms   673 ms  168.209.2.12
6   846 ms   786 ms   580 ms  168.209.100.13
7   605 ms   751 ms   820 ms  csw5-pkl-te1-7.ip.isnet.net [196.26.0.188]
8   448 ms   337 ms   523 ms  196.23.168.187
```

And from my machine:

```
1    <1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.254
2   522 ms   667 ms   296 ms  196-215-156-1.dynamic.isadsl.co.za [196.215.156.1]
3   344 ms   446 ms   674 ms  cdsl1-ctn-vl2376.ip.isnet.net [196.38.72.205]
4   729 ms   675 ms   538 ms  196.35.115.128
5   470 ms   500 ms   454 ms  168.209.2.12
6   379 ms   554 ms   702 ms  168.209.100.13
7   739 ms   734 ms   393 ms  csw5-pkl-te1-7.ip.isnet.net [196.26.0.188]
8   496 ms   432 ms   395 ms  196.23.168.176
```

---

Today (3 July) I have:

- Called Telkom and they say everything is fine from their end.
- Called the ISP who also say everything is fine on their end.
- Unplugged the two drives I installed over the weekend thinking they might be the cause of the problems.
- Spoken to my brother who also runs an internet business and also reports slow connections.

---

**Tracert at 10:22pm - 3 July**

Switched back to the old router

```
1    <1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  10.0.0.2
2    20 ms    20 ms    20 ms  196-215-156-1.dynamic.isadsl.co.za [196.215.156.1]
3    21 ms    22 ms    22 ms  vlan2473.cdsl2-ctn.isdsl.net [196.38.72.193]
4    24 ms    23 ms    23 ms  196.35.115.136
5    22 ms    22 ms    22 ms  168.209.6.12
6    44 ms    45 ms    44 ms  168.209.100.13
7    45 ms    44 ms    44 ms  csw6-pkl-tg2-7.ip.isnet.net [168.209.1.189]
8    45 ms    44 ms    45 ms  za196-23-168-154.cache.googlevideo.com [196.23.168.154]
```

---

**Tracert at 07:00 am - 4 July**

Testing this morning again, these are the results. Slightly worse again from last night's test.

Tracing route to www.google.com [196.23.168.144]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

```
1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  10.0.0.2
2   235 ms   295 ms   217 ms  196-215-156-1.dynamic.isadsl.co.za [196.215.156.1]
3   233 ms   124 ms   171 ms  cdsl1-ctn-vl2376.ip.isnet.net [196.38.72.205]
4   122 ms   296 ms   141 ms  196.35.115.128
5   312 ms   151 ms   132 ms  168.209.2.12
6   154 ms   202 ms   191 ms  168.209.100.13
7   139 ms   163 ms   348 ms  csw6-pkl-te1-7.ip.isnet.net [196.26.0.189]
8   260 ms   158 ms   305 ms  za196-23-168-144.cache.googlevideo.com [196.23.168.144]
```

---

Comment: You have to start listing what you tried. Your question is so broad you can't expect us to list all possibilities. Give us something to start with.

Comment: If you've done a lot, than you surely have more information for us, such as if it happens at specific times of day, days of the week, etc, what your network setup is, operating systems, is it on all devices or just one, etc.

Comment: Sorry guys, I have added an edit to the question.

Comment: Do you know anything about the network structure behind your router? Would the technicians have been able to spot faulty cabling (e.g. a joint on the point of collapsing)? My first thought was your neighbours downloads, but you say you tested at different times, I assume also early in the morning. You may want to keep a log of the slow times. Also see if you can find software that continuously monitors your uploads (and maybe downloads) and lets you inspect its logs for unusually heavy traffic. Would the technicians have detected a DDOS attack (unlikely, but)? Did you monitor your CPU usage?

Comment: Try installing [NetWorx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) and check the log after few days. You can also check your connection if you have a router that can be flashed with DD-WRT. Another question would be if you have tried without a router and just ISP modem.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will implement these suggestions and monitor it again. Then come back to you.

Comment: I am going to keep a log of this and point my ISP to this page too in the hope that it resolves the problem. I've added the latest tracert since istalling NetWorx and you can see now that everything is running smoothly.